# How to install MUPDF library on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, pdf, mupdf

I've CentOS 6 and I want to make install from source of MuPDF library on it. I've tried using different links over internet but no success, Can anyone help me?...

Source of MuPDF is available at
https://mupdf.com/downloads/index.html

I've tried this link on last.
http://software-engineering-and-computers.blogspot.com/2013/10/building-mupdf-on-centos.html

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you try, what kind of errors/problems you get?

Comment: After repeating all steps, there is no file mutool or mupdf available on server at /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib

Comment: Add in question all the steps you do and warnings/errors you get.

Comment: I did all steps from http://software-engineering-and-computers.blogspot.com/2013/10/building-mupdf-on-centos.html this url... and got no error..

Comment: (1) You should be looking for the binaries (mupdf-x11, mupdf-gl, or mutool) in `/usr/local/bin` (if you did a simple `make install`). That is [the default install directory](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=a9539342880034f34a3d72281637539ab377883b;hb=HEAD#l291) for the apps and tools. (2) That blog post is out of date. The third-party sources are now bundled in the source archive. You should be able to (a) get the [1.14.0 source](https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-1.14.0-source.tar.gz), (b) unpack it, (c) `cd mupdf-1.14.0-source`, and run `make install`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of installing on CentOS (or any other os) is using anaconda.

Once you make sure that you have anaconda installed, run the command:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge mupdf
```

That's it!

If you wanna however not use anaconda (I warn you, it will be nowhere as easy as it is with anaconda), you can follow these steps:

1). Get the MuPDF source from the site `wget https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-1.14.0-source.tar.gz` and decompress it (latest version as of writing. Others available here: https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/).

2). MuPDF also has a repository on GitHub. This, however, is the latest development version! Do not use it: it is probably not be compatible with the current PyMuPDF.

3). Set environment variables: `export CFLAGS="-fPIC"` (on CentOS 5, `export CFLAGS="-fPIC -std=gnu99"` to resolve errors about missing a definition for `NAN` symbol in the `thirdparty/mujs` folder).

4). Run the initial make: `make HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLFW=no HAVE_GLUT=no prefix=/usr/local`

5). If no issues occur install: `make HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLFW=no HAVE_GLUT=no prefix=/usr/local install`

Reference: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/wiki/Ubuntu-Installation-Experience